# How to extract DEM (Digital Elevation Model) from 3D model

Tags: export

How can I extract a Digital Elevation Model from a 3D model of a building, made with SketchUp, using Blender or any other software?

Comment: What is *"Dem"*?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms DEM Digital Elevation Model (used mostly in topography)

Comment: Blender has no built in support not read or write Dem files. There are a couple of scripts out there to import dem into blender but I don't know of any to export. You'll have to do the conversion to dem in other software.

Comment: read: http://kodex.tumblr.com/post/37038839550/visualising-qgis-data-with-blender

Comment: and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87514/open-source-tool-to-convert-a-dem-to-a-3d-model